# Unable to hide division on button click (code behind) ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, division

The pageload event is able to be executed, however, I can't **change the div visibility** after a button click. (Even when the Responce.Redirect("product.aspx") is working)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SQLCon.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SDMConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SQLCon.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Customer", SQLCon);
    len = da.Fill(dt);
    userview.Visible = true;
    memberview.Visible = false;


}
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = UserName.Text;
    string pass = Password.Text;
    int counter = 0;


    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string usernameCheck = row["Username"].ToString();
        string passCheck = row["Pass"].ToString();

        if (username == usernameCheck && pass == passCheck)
        {
            counter = 1;
            break;

        }
        else
        {
            counter = 0;
        }

    }

    if (counter == 1)
    {
        memberview.Visible = true;
        userview.Visible = false;
        Response.Redirect("product.aspx");
        Session["user"] = username.ToString();
        lblLoggedUser.Text = Session["user"].ToString();

    }
    else
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('Error Username or Password!');</script>");
    }

}
```

However, when the code is as below, it's ***working***:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    userview.Visible = true;
    memberview.Visible = false;
}
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        memberview.Visible = true;
        userview.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: You did redirect, why you need to change visibility of part of prev. page?

Comment: The codes i posted are from my masterpage, so I need to change the visibility of the content of my navbar, if the user successfully logged in. @MehdiDehghani

Comment: After redirecting, the `Page_Load` event will be fired again, just like first time you open a page, you're looking for something is not possible, based on your shared codes.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani do you have any advise for changes?

Comment: I think you need an authentication system that provide some useful mechanism to detect user state, you can use `ASP.NET Identity`, more info here: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project